# How to Order By table inside nested query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

How can I order the results of this by the SO table which is inside the nested query?

If I change the ORDER BY to i.created_date (which is another valid column) the query works.  How do I accomplish this?

```
 SELECT *
 FROM   invoice AS i
 WHERE  i.so_sid = ( SELECT s.so_sid
    FROM so AS s
    WHERE i.so_sid = s.so_sid AND s.created_date >= '2014-10-01'
    ORDER BY s.created_date)
 ORDER BY s.created_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join rather than using a subquery:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM invoice AS i
JOIN so AS s ON i.so_sid = s.so_sid
WHERE s.created_date >= '2014-10-01'
ORDER by s.created_date
```

In general, whenever you find yourself using a subquery in `WHERE`, you should strongly consider using a join instead. It's likely that it will be more efficient as well.